# How to check whether term is empty after pruning of tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am using tfidfvectorizer to score terms from many different corpus.
Here is my code

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words = 'english', min_df = 0.5)
for corpus in all_corpus:
    tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

The number of documents in each corpus is various, so when building the vocabulary, some corpus remains empty and return an error:

```
after pruning, no terms remain. Try a lower min_df or higher max_df
```

I don't want to change the min or max DF. What I need is when there is no terms, the transforming process is skipped. So I made a conditional filter like below

```
for corpus in all_corpus:
    tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
    if tfidf.shape[0] > 0:
    \\execute some code here
```

However, the condition couldn't work. Is there way to fix this?

All answers and comments are really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, a minimum working example for your problem is I believe, the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words = 'english', min_df = 0.5)
tfidf.fit_transform(['not I you'])
```

I could not replicate an error message that contains the part of the error message you share, but this gives me a `ValueError` as all the words in my document are English stop words. (The code runs if one removes `stop_words = 'english'` in the snippet above.)

One way of handling the error in the case of a for-loop is to use a try/except block.

```
for corpus in all_corpus:
    try:
        tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
    except ValueError:
        print('Transforming process skipped')
        # Here you can do more stuff
        continue  # go to the beginning of the for-loop to start the next iteration
    # Here goes the rest of the code for corpus for which the transform functioned
```